# Как правильно подключить Interface Color Picker?

Tags: jquery

Использую Interface Color Picker плагин (jquery). Проблема заключается в том, что я не могу подключить его для многих input. Получается что всегда работает только с первым, а нужно чтобы для каждого input ставился свой цвет.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="js/jquery/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery/ifx.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery/idrop.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery/idrag.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery/iutil.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery/islider.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery/color_picker/color_picker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <link href="js/jquery/color_picker/color_picker.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <!-- compliance patch for microsoft browsers -->
        <!--[if lt IE 7]>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/jquery/color_picker/color_picker-ie6.css" type="text/css">
        <![endif]-->
        <!--[if gte IE 7]>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/jquery/color_picker/color_picker-ie7.css" type="text/css">
        <![endif]-->
        <style>
            form > ul > li > a > div {
                display: inline-block;
                width: 19px;
                height: 19px;
                border-top: 1px solid #A9A9A9;
                border-right: 1px solid #A9A9A9;
                border-bottom: 1px solid #A9A9A9;
                margin-bottom: -6px;
            }
            input {
                margin-bottom: 10px;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            $(document).ready (
                function() {
                    $.ColorPicker.init();
                }
            );
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="form_action.php" method="post">
            <ul>
                <li>Строка 11 - Ссылки a - <input type="text" id="myhexcode" value=""><a href="javascript:void(0);" rel="colorpicker&objcode=myhexcode&objshow=myshowcolor&showrgb=1&okfunc=myokfunc"><div id="myshowcolor"></div></a></li>
                <li>Строка 14 - Заголовки h - <input type="text" id="myhexcode" value=""><a href="javascript:void(0);" rel="colorpicker&objcode=myhexcode&objshow=myshowcolor&showrgb=1&okfunc=myokfunc"><div id="myshowcolor"></div></a></li>
                <li>Строка 35 - Основа левого меню - <input type="text" id="myhexcode" value=""><a href="javascript:void(0);" rel="colorpicker&objcode=myhexcode&objshow=myshowcolor&showrgb=1&okfunc=myokfunc"><div id="myshowcolor"></div></a></li>
                <li>Строка 48 - Второй внутреннего левого меню - <input type="text" id="myhexcode" value=""><a href="javascript:void(0);" rel="colorpicker&objcode=myhexcode&objshow=myshowcolor&showrgb=1&okfunc=myokfunc"><div id="myshowcolor"></div></a></li>
                <li>Строка 51 - Второй левого меню - <input type="text" id="myhexcode" value=""><a href="javascript:void(0);" rel="colorpicker&objcode=myhexcode&objshow=myshowcolor&showrgb=1&okfunc=myokfunc"><div id="myshowcolor"></div></a></li>
                <li>Строка 60 - Полоски сайта - <input type="text" id="myhexcode" value=""><a href="javascript:void(0);" rel="colorpicker&objcode=myhexcode&objshow=myshowcolor&showrgb=1&okfunc=myokfunc"><div id="myshowcolor"></div></a></li>
                <li>Строка 70 - Цвет главного меню - <input type="text" id="myhexcode" value=""><a href="javascript:void(0);" rel="colorpicker&objcode=myhexcode&objshow=myshowcolor&showrgb=1&okfunc=myokfunc"><div id="myshowcolor"></div></a></li>
                <li>Строка 75 - Цвет нижней линии - <input type="text" id="myhexcode" value=""><a href="javascript:void(0);" rel="colorpicker&objcode=myhexcode&objshow=myshowcolor&showrgb=1&okfunc=myokfunc"><div id="myshowcolor"></div></a></li>
                <li>Строка 76 - Цвет выпадающего списка - <input type="text" id="myhexcode" value=""><a href="javascript:void(0);" rel="colorpicker&objcode=myhexcode&objshow=myshowcolor&showrgb=1&okfunc=myokfunc"><div id="myshowcolor"></div></a></li>
                <li>Строка 79 - Второй главного меню - <input type="text" id="myhexcode" value=""><a href="javascript:void(0);" rel="colorpicker&objcode=myhexcode&objshow=myshowcolor&showrgb=1&okfunc=myokfunc"><div id="myshowcolor"></div></a></li>
            </ul>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Вот демо самого плагина: [Color Picker](http://www.intelliance.fr/jquery/color_picker/)

Структура index.html практически идентична. Только отличается тем, что у меня много input, а в демо он один.

Может как то классы менять нужно или по другому сделать инициализацию плагина? Помогите пожалуйста, буду очень признателен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У каждого `input` должен быть уникальный ID (ID вообще всегда должен быть уникальным на странице).

Далее после input идет тег `a`, у которого есть атрибут `rel="colorpicker&objcode=myhexcode&objshow=myshowcolor&showrgb=1&okfunc=myokfunc"`

Давайте его рассмотрим:

- `objcode=myhexcode` - это ID у input (мы его должны поменять)
- `objshow=myshowcolor` - это ID у следующего после a тега div - он тоже должен быть уникальным!
- `okfunc=myokfunc` - какую функцию выполнить после корректного выполнения. вам это, вроде как, не нужно. Можно просто удалить.

Что мы получаем?

```
<ul>
    <li>Строка 11 - Ссылки a - <input type="text" id="myhexcode1" value="">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" rel="colorpicker&objcode=myhexcode1&objshow=myshowcolor1&showrgb=1">
            <div id="myshowcolor1"></div>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>Строка 14 - Заголовки h - <input type="text" id="myhexcode2" value="">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" rel="colorpicker&objcode=myhexcode2&objshow=myshowcolor2&showrgb=1">
            <div id="myshowcolor2"></div>
        </a>
    </li>     
    ...   
</ul>
```